# Working Craps program

Tags: python, beginner, python-3.x, game, dice

How can I make this better?

```
import random

def roll():
    input("Press Enter to roll")
    dice = random.randint(1, 6) + random.randint(1, 6)
    print("You rolled a {}" .format(dice))
    return dice

def checkRoll(dice):
    if dice == 7 or dice == 11:
        print("You win")
        playAgain()
    elif dice == 2 or dice == 3 or dice == 12:
        print("You lose")
        playAgain()
    else:
        print("Time to try to roll the point")
        reRoll(dice)

def reRoll(point):
    dice = roll()
    if dice == point:
        print("You win")
        playAgain()
    elif dice == 7:
        print("You lose")
        playAgain()
    else:
        reRoll(point)
def play():
    print("Do you wanna play Craps? Y/n ")
    response = input(">>> ").lower()
    if response == "y":
        checkRoll(roll())
    else:
        input("ENTER to quit")

def playAgain():
    response = input("Play Again? Y/n >>>").lower()
    if response == "y":
        checkRoll(roll())
    else:
        input("ENTER to quit")


play()
```

Answer (score 3):

**PEP8**

1.Python uses underscore as naming separator in function and variable names, see [PEP8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/)

2.Two blank lines are used to separate function/classes

**Improvements.**

To make your module reusable you should use `if __name__ == '__main__'` condtion before invoking your main function.

So instead of calling `play()` you should do:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    play()
```

Your play_again and play function got difference only in print statements, so you can just combine them into a single function.

```
def start_game(first_run=False):
    if first_run:
        print("Do you wanna play Craps? Y/n ")
        response = input(">>> ").lower()
    else:
        response = input("Play Again? Y/n >>>").lower()
    if response == "y":
        check_roll(roll())
    else:
        input("ENTER to quit")
```

*Note*

I've renamed function into `start_game` since I find `play` a bit confusing. But you can keep your name if you want.

Now if you look at your check_roll and reroll function they are also the same except for win and lose conditions, so you can also combine them into a single one like this:

```
def check_roll(dice, win_conditions=(7, 11), lose_conditions=(2, 3, 12)):
    if dice in win_conditions:
        print("You win")
        start_game()
    elif dice in lose_conditions:
        print("You lose")
        start_game()
    else:
        print("Time to try to roll the point")
        check_roll(roll(), (dice,), (7,))
```

Also, I did small improvement to roll() function so now you can see values of dice you've rolled:

```
def roll():
    input("Press Enter to roll")
    dice = random.randint(1, 6), random.randint(1, 6)
    print("You rolled a {}" .format(dice))
    return sum(dice)
```

So in the end, what we have is this:

```
import random


def roll():
    input("Press Enter to roll")
    dice = random.randint(1, 6), random.randint(1, 6)
    print("You rolled a {}" .format(dice))
    return sum(dice)


def check_roll(dice, win_conditions=(7, 11), lose_conditions=(2, 3, 12)):
    if dice in win_conditions:
        print("You win")
        start_game()
    elif dice in lose_conditions:
        print("You lose")
        start_game()
    else:
        print("Time to try to roll the point")
        check_roll(roll(), (dice,), (7,))


def start_game(first_run=False):
    if first_run:
        print("Do you wanna play Craps? Y/n ")
        response = input(">>> ")
    else:
        response = input("Play Again? Y/n >>>")
    if response.lower() == "y":
        check_roll(roll())
    else:
        input("ENTER to quit")


if __name__ == '__main__':
    start_game(True)
```

Answer (score 2):

Your code is quite good, it's testable. But it may abruptly break as it uses recursion.

Spam `y` and enter for a reasonable period of time and you should get:

> ```
> RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded
> ```

To fix this, change from using recursion to a loop.
To do this merge; `play`, `reRoll`, and `playAgain`.
And; `checkRoll`, and `reRoll`, should return, rather than call *any* of these functions.

Firstly merge `reRoll` with `checkRoll`, to do this you want to use a `while` loop, remove the else in `reRoll` and replace all `playAgain` calls with `return`.
This can get something like:

```
def checkRoll(point):
    if point == 7 or point == 11:
        print("You win")
        return
    elif point == 2 or point == 3 or point == 12:
        print("You lose")
        return
    else:
        print("Time to try to roll the point")
        while True:
            dice = roll()
            if dice == point:
                print("You win")
                return
            elif dice == 7:
                print("You lose")
                return
```

After this merge `play` and `playAgain`.
To do this use a while loop and call the above `checkRoll` with the code to play again there.
This can get:

```
def play():
    print("Do you wanna play Craps? Y/n ")
    while True:
        response = input(">>> ").lower()
        if response != "y":
            break
        checkRoll(roll())
        print("Play Again? Y/n")
    input("ENTER to quit")
```

---

After removing the recursion there are still a couple of ways I'd change the code:

1. You can check if an item is in a list, rather than using `or`. `'a' in ['a', 'b']`.
2. The code should default empty input to `y` if when using `Y/n`. To do this compare to `n` rather than `y`.
3. I'd move the prints to the main.
4. I'd move the rolling line in `roll`, to it's own function. So if you need to roll without user input at a later date you can.

All this can get: (The comments are only there to show what I changed)

```
import random

# 4
def roll_():
    return random.randint(1, 6) + random.randint(1, 6)

def roll():
    input("Press Enter to roll")
    dice = roll_()
    print("You rolled a {}" .format(dice))
    return dice

def checkRoll(dice):
    if dice in [7, 11]: # 1
        return True # 3
    elif dice in [2, 3, 12]: # 1
        return False # 3
    else:
        print("Time to try to roll the point")
        while True:
            dice = roll()
            if dice == point:
                return True # 3
            elif dice == 7:
                return False # 3

def play():
    print("Do you wanna play Craps? Y/n ")
    while True:
        response = input(">>> ").lower()
        if response == "n": # 2
            break
        if checkRoll(roll()):
            print("you win") # 3
        else:
            print("you lose") # 3

    input("ENTER to quit")

play()
```